# How to use regex match in string array?

Tags: javascript, arrays, matching, string-matching, regexp-substr

I want to this : When the entered value matches the value of the my array , write the matches value.

so this is my code :

//my array as the following :

```
var checkNames = (document.getElementById("KPIorCounterList").value.split("\n").map(element => element.trim())).filter(v=>v != "");
```

my another array : `myarray= ["RAB Video call drop %",RAB PS R99 drop % ","RAB PS HSDPA drop %"]`

For example ; when write RAB* to textare, I should to see, starting with "RAB"

I guess, My code should be as follows:

```
  for (var i = 0; i < checkNames.length; i++) {
                    for (var j = 0; j < myarray.length; j++) {
           // var str = myarray[j].split(" "); // I am not sure for his.

            I want to this for here : (pseudo code)
            for example checkName[i] == RAB*
            if (checkName[i].match("match condition") == myarray[j])
            alert(myarray[j]);
            //I should show output myarray[j] == RAB Video call drop %",RAB PS R99 drop % ","RAB PS HSDPA drop %"
       }
    }
```

How can I do ?
Please..

Comment: Don't really have an answer for you, but i think `myarray["j"]` should be `myarray[j]`..

Comment: checkNames is temp array?

Comment: No, different array @VladuIonut

Comment: your pseudo code is not so clear , which is temp array in there

Comment: sorry, I edited my code. @VladuIonut

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
function check(){
var checkNames = (document.getElementById("KPIorCounterList").value.split("\n").map(element => element.trim())).filter(v=>v != "");
var myarray = ["RAB Video call drop %", "RAB PS R99 drop % ", "RAB PS HSDPA drop %"]
for (var i = 0; i < checkNames.length; i++) {
  console.log("results for", checkNames[i])
  for (var j = 0; j < myarray.length; j++) {

      var matchString = myarray[j].match(new RegExp(checkNames[i].replace('*','.*')));
    if (matchString && myarray.indexOf(matchString[0])!==-1) {
      console.log(myarray[j]);
    }
    //I should show output myarray[j] == RAB Video call drop %",RAB PS R99 drop % ","RAB PS HSDPA drop %"
  }
}
  }
```

```html
<textarea id="KPIorCounterList"></textarea>
<button onclick="check()">Check</button>
```

Comment: checkName came from 'textarea.value '. I want to this : textarea.value is array and if array eleman is : ''RAB*'' the above code should work. How can I control it ? please @VladuIonut

Answer (score 1):

@eagle, I believe this is the input to `checkNames`. If so, here is my solution -

```
var checkNames = ['RAB*'];
var myarray = ["RAB Video call drop %","RAB PS R99 drop % ","RAB PS HSDPA drop %"];

for (var i = 0; i < checkNames.length; i++) {
    for (var j = 0; j < myarray.length; j++) {
        var formatRegExpr = checkNames[i].replace('*','.*');
        var re = new RegExp(formatRegExpr, 'g');
        alert(myarray[j].match(re));
    }
}
```

Accept this answer if it solves your requirement.

Comment: I'm trying to learn so  `var re = new RegExp(formatRegExpr, 'g');` What 'g' is? @dinesh

Comment: g - global search flag. Good place to learn - [regexr-dot-com](http://regexr.com/)

Comment: checkName came from 'textarea.value '. I want to this :  textarea.value is array and if array eleman is  : ''RAB*''   the above code should work. How can I control it ? please @dinesh